# Pass parameter to Flask API method

Tags: python, api, flask, parameters

I'm pretty new to Flask APIs, so I hope this will be pretty easy to solve.

I'm working on an API (right now it has only one endpoint, but as soon as I manage to implement its functionality more will follow). I generated my API with the swagger editor and am trying to implement the methods. I managed to implement a GET method which takes no variables and returns a json file.

What I'm trying right now is to pass variable to this method to do some things.

My directory structure is like this:

```
swagger_server/
    |---->__main__.py
    |---->controllers
           '---->default_controller.py
```

My `__main__.py` file (I deleted a few empty lines to make this question shorter):

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/env python3
  3 import connexion
  5 from swagger_server import encoder
  7 
  8 def main():
  9     app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='./swagger/')
 10     app.app.json_encoder = encoder.JSONEncoder
 11     app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'Test API'}, pythonic_params=True)
 12     app.run(port=8080)
 14 
 15 if __name__ == '__main__':
 16     main()
```

My `default_controller.py`:

```
  1 import connexion
  2 import six
  3 import os
  4 import json
 60
 61 def get_supported_types(test):  # noqa: E501
 62     """Retrieve supported types for number test
 63     param:    test = id of supported type
 64     :rtype: InlineResponse200
 65     """
 66     print(test)
 70
 71     return 'blabla'
```

Without a parameter I was able to receive data with curl like this `curl -H 'Authorization: 0123' -H --trace-ascii /tmp/dump.txt  'http://127.0.0.1:3080/v1/supported_types'`

I tried to add an extra header with `-H "test: 15"`, to add it to the URL `http://127.0.0.1:3080/v1/supported_types?test=15` (which led to a 500 Server Error) and `http://127.0.0.1:3080/v1/supported_types/?test=15` (which led to a 404 Not Found Error).

Also I read a little bit about @app.route which I tried but that didn't really work:

```
@app.route("/v1/supported_types/", methods=['GET'])
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me pass this argument to the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put name of variables on route and on method which you will use then you can handle

```
@my_bp.route('/my_route/<int:id_report>')
def report(id_report=1):
    report = make_pdf(Report.query.get(id_report))
    return send_file(report, attachment_filename="My_Report.pdf", as_attachment=True )
```

Comment: What do I have to use instead of my_bp? everything I tried to put there generated a "NameError: name 'default_controller' is not defined"

Comment: I use blueprints as recommended but you using ```app``` directly so by you're way should be ```@app.route('my_route/<int:id_report>')```

Comment: Sadly it doesn't (I receive a NameError like at the bottom of my initial question) any idea how to fix it (I think it may be because of the structure of my directories which I would like to keep like it is)?

Comment: You must initialize your app like this:
`from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
`
Then initialize api of swagger like here: https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/swagger.html#configuring-try-it-out

I suggest you try make rest-api with flask before using any libraries because it's simple and you will understand better what library is doing for you